# Iterate over a map in Rascal

Tags: functional-programming, rascal

I'm trying to create a map comprehension over a map in this structure:

`map[Node, set[Node]]`

And my map comprehension is something like:

`(currentNode: {currentNode} | <currentNode, _>  <- dominanceSet);`

But I'm getting this error:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve a similar behaviour using another strategy?

Comment: Is `map[Node, set[Node]]` only the target type, or is this also the type of `dominanceSet`?

Comment: I'm guessing based on the error message that it's both, I just want to be sure so I can give an appropriate answer.

Comment: same here. don't mind if I did Mark?

Comment: That's fine, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generator for maps in Rascal produces the key values (and not some form of "entries" or tuples).

So the code would be:

```
(currentNode: {currentNode} | currentNode <- dominanceSet)
```

Note that there are some specialized functions in the standard library for faster indexing relations, like in `Relations` there is `map[&K, set[&V]] index(rel[&K, &V] R);`

Comment: so I'm assuming from the error message that `dominanceSet` is actually a map.